# Azure AKS and Application Gateway returning 404

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I have a AKS cluster deployed with an Application Gateway. These are all docker images running on the AKS cluster with a simple ingress. They all run on the same default namespace. One is a Vue frontend, the second is a Java spring backend, the last being a Fullstack Tomcat image. All three services ran completely fine without any issues; however, today all of the 3 services gave back a 404 error (without any changes to the cluster to my knowledge).

When testing for the health of these services, I was still able to kubectl to all the services. In addition, the Health Probe on Azure Application Gateway returned a healthy 200 status code for all three services.

I have tried removing the workloads and adding them back again. I have tried removing the services then adding them back again. I have done the same for the ingress as well.

I have also tried setting up the entire cluster from a fresh AKS cluster from scratch from a new AKS cluster, all three images perform without any issues.

The Yaml for a application on the AKS network looks like:

```
- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: testvuefe
  spec:
    replicas: 2
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: testvuefe
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: testvuefe
      spec:
        nodeSelector:
          kubernetes.io/os: linux
        containers:
          - name: testvuefe
            image: testdocker.azurecr.io/testvuefe:latest
            ports:
              - containerPort: 80
            resources:
              requests:
                cpu: '0'
                memory: '0'
              limits:
                cpu: '128'
                memory: 512G
            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: "/fileShare"
                name: volume
        volumes:
          - name: volume
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: aks-azurefile
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: testvuefe-service
  spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    ports:
      - targetPort: 80
        name: port80
        port: 80
        protocol: TCP
    selector:
      app: testvuefe
- apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: testvuefe-ingress
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
      appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-path: /user
      appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/cookie-based-affinity: "true"
  spec:
    rules:
      - host: test.wbsoft.co.kr
        http:
          paths:
            - path: /
              pathType: Prefix
              backend:
                service:
                  name: testvuefe-service
                  port:
                    number: 80
```

As this issue as occurred once on a cluster, I need to understand what is causing these issues so that it does not happen during production. It would also be great if a solution can be found for the issue.